# Why isn't TokenAwarePolicy the default for the Datastax java driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Are there drawbacks to using the TokenAwarePolicy over the current default of RoundRobinPolicy?

It seems to me that routing requests to nodes identified as being replicas by the routing-key should always be preferable, and a RoundRobinPolicy wrapped by TokenAwarePolicy should be the default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real drawback to using TokenAwarePolicy and in fact we've changed the default in recent releases (2.0.2) so it is now using token aware.

Comment: so what would happen in case of batch writes? is there a way we can send batch of writes of one partition to its corresponding node (without any coordinator)?